# Error: key $conditionalHandlers must not start with '$' mongodb

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue with mongodb and especially the mongoose package for node.js. I have the following schema :

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var location = new Schema ({
  nomville: {type: String, required: true},
  description: {type: String, required: true},
  quartier: [quartier],
  critere: [misc],
  modified: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var misc = new Schema ({
  publictransp: {type: Number},
  culture: {type: Number},
  traffic: {type: Number},
  nature: {type: Number},
  supermarket: {type: Number},
  school: {type: Number},
  sport: {type: Number},
  nightlife: {type: Number},
  mean: {type: Number}
});

var rue = new Schema ({
  nomrue: {type: String},
  modified: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var quartier = new Schema ({
  nomquartier: {type: String},
  listerue: [rue],
  modified: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

var ObjModel = mongoose.model('Obj',location);
```

And when I try to post an object of this schema with a Jquery query I get this :

[Error: key $conditionalHandlers must not start with '$']

Any idea ? I'm completely stuck with this one.

EDIT1 : here's the post function :

```
//CREATE PRODUCTS
app.post('/api/products', function(req,res){
  var product;
  console.log("POST: ");
  console.log(req.body);
  product = new ObjModel({
    nomville: req.body.nomville,
    description: req.body.description,
    quartier: [quartier],
    critere: [misc],
  });
  product.save(function(err){
    if (!err) {
      return console.log("created");
    } else {
   return console.log(err);
    }
  });
  return res.send(product);
});
```

EDIT2 : here's the query

```
 jQuery.post("/api/products", {
  "nomville": "Strasbourg",
  "description": "Ville de Strasbourg",
  "quartier": [
    {
      "nomquartier": "Centre",
      "listerue": [
          {
            "nomrue": "22 Novembre"
          },
          {
            "nomrue": "Abattoir"
          },
          {
            "nomrue": "Fonderie"
          },
          {
            "nomrue": "Francs Bourgeois"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nomquartier": "Cité de l'Ill",
      "listerue": [
          {
            "nomrue": "Anguille (chemin de l)"
          },
          {
            "nomrue": "Civelles (promenade des)"
          },
          {
            "nomrue": "Hechner (rue)"
          },
          {
            "nomrue": "Phario (pont)"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nomquartier": "Krutenau",
      "listerue": [
          {
            "nomrue": "Abreuvoir (rue de l)"
          },
          {
            "nomrue": "Bain Finkwiller (rue du)"
          },
          {
            "nomrue": "Fustel de Coulanges (quai)"
          },
          {
           "nomrue": "Hôpital (place de l)"
          }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "critere":[
    {
      "publictransp": 2,
      "culture": 8,
      "traffic": 5,
      "nature": 7,
      "supermarket": 3,
      "school": 5,
      "sport": 6,
      "nightlife": 4,
      "mean": 5
    },
  ]
}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("Post resposne:"); console.dir(data); console.log(textStatus);         console.dir(jqXHR);
});
```

That's what I get after posting the query:

```
[
  {
    "nomville": "Strasbourg",
    "description": "Ville de Strasbourg",
    "_id": "526ecdd3a78290010c000004",
    "__v": 0,
    "modified": "2013-10-28T20:49:23.235Z",
    "critere": [],
    "quartiers": [
      {
        "_id": "526ecdd3a78290010c000005",
       "listerue": []
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is this normal ??

Comment: What do you mean with "when I try to post an object of this schema with a Jquery query". Could you please post the source code where you call the model.

Comment: We need to see the server side code that handles the POST request to "/api/products". The '$' has nothing to do with jquery. That's a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to `critere` and `misc` in the `location` schema definition before either of those schemas are defined.  This is causing that somewhat cryptic error, likely due to mongoose piecing together an invalid query because of the unexpected `undefined` values in the schema definition.

Beyond this, I don't know what you're trying to do here:

```
product = new ObjModel({
  nomville: req.body.nomville,
  description: req.body.description,

  // Are the next two lines a mistake?  It appears as though you're trying
  // to create an object using the schemas.
  quartier: [quartier],
  critere: [misc],
});
```