# MongoDB Error Error: key $conditionalHandlers must not start with '$'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm struggling with running my NodeExpress App with Mongo on my server. When trying to write to write to the DB the following Error occurs. Only certain models seem to produce this failure, others work without problem.

Its especially weird, because it runs without any problems on my local machine. Using Same Node and MongoDB versions, bot equally deployed via git.

The error really doesn't give much information on where to look for the error. Anyone has a Tip where to start?

```
Error: key $conditionalHandlers must not start with '$'
    at Error (native)
    at serializeInto (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:741:19)
    at serializeObject (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:300:18)
    at serializeInto (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:766:17)
    at serializeObject (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:300:18)
    at serializeInto (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:766:17)
    at serializeObject (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:300:18)
    at serializeInto (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:608:17)
    at serializeObject (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:300:18)
    at serializeInto (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:766:17)
    at serializeObject (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:300:18)
    at serializeInto (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:608:17)
    at serializeObject (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:300:18)
    at serializeInto (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:766:17)
    at serialize (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/bson.js:49:27)
    at Query.toBin (/root/casinofuchs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/commands.js:143:25)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643732/error-key-conditionalhandlers-must-not-start-with-mongodb

Comment: I've seen that threat, didn't really apply to my situation though. My Schemas are in order.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like I've found the problem.

I had in my models the following definiton:

```
    logo:{ type:[ImageSchema], default:[ImageSchema] }
```

Switching this back to:

```
    logo:{ type:[ImageSchema] } 
    or
    logo:[ImageSchema]
```

...made it work again.

This somehow stopped working, even on my Macbook now.
Could it be, that there was an update of some Plugin these days that made this fail?

What would be the proper Solution to have a default Value for ImageSchema in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This error message suggests that a field name is violating a MongoDB naming restriction. Specifically, field names [must not start with a dollar sign character](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names).

Comment: Mh. I have no dollar sign charakter anywhere in my models. Also, why is it running on my Mac and also inside a docker-container, but not on my Ubuntu server?